# Wipe Out Current Workspace ( Jenkins )

Tags: jenkins

I dont know where my workspace 
Jenkins notice that

Everyone can help me

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config / general / Use Customer workspace 
set directory = **D:\D_User_BW_Katalon\Katalon Studio\Group_User_Duplicate_Role**

I have workspace Right Now

[image]

[image]